# Eloquent sortBy - Specify asc or desc

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-4, eloquent

Trying sort my eloquent collection:

```
$collection->sortBy('field');
```

There is no information in Laravel 4's docs on how to choose descending or ascending for this sort method.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Laravel 5

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortby

#### Laravel 4

https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_sortBy

#### Usage

```
$collection->sortBy('field', [], true); // true for descending
```

Comment: Thanks! Never knew about that site. Went for sortByDesc().

Comment: `sortBy('field', [], true)` returns `arsort(): Argument #2 ($flags) must be of type int, array given in file` error!!!

Comment: Note that the second argument should be a [sorting type flag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.constants.php), such as `SORT_REGULAR` (the default flag used by `sortBy()`), instead of an array.

Answer (score 58):

To sort by **ASC**: [Laravel Docs - sortBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortby)

`$collection->sortBy('field');`

To sort by **DESC**: [Laravel Docs - sortByDesc()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortbydesc)

`$collection->sortByDesc('field');`

Comment: omg... thank you. I just spent 30 minutes trying to figure out how to sort descending. No idea how many times I scrolled past it there

Answer (score 7):

In 4.2, the second parameter needs to be an int, SORT_REGULAR is default

https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_sortBy

$collection->sortBy('field', SORT_REGULAR, true); //true for descending

Comment: u can also check the api https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_sortBy