# How to sort a collected based on descending order in laravel?

Tags: laravel, sorting, laravel-collection

I am very new to the laravel , i have one collection i want to sort the collection based on the id by using `sortBy()` method but it's not working,please help me to achieve this thing ..

```
 $new=collect($transformed['data']);
       $v= $new->sortByDesc(function($prod,$key){
            return count($prod['id']);
        });
        dd($v->all());
```

error:- ***count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable***

Comment: Just use `$v = $new->sortByDesc('id');`

Comment: Similar Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649113/eloquent-sortby-specify-asc-or-desc#answer-30649212 This might help.