# ordery by descending with foreign key on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

i want to sort my data by foreign key in my table. how can i do that?

here's my query

"jenis_pengiriman_id" is my foreign key in biaya_pengiriman table

its BiayaPengirimanController

```
   public function index()
{
    $biaya_pengiriman = BiayaPengiriman::latest()->get();
    return view('biaya_pengiriman.index', compact('biaya_pengiriman'));
}
```

its my query for relationship on foreign key

```
public function jenis()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(JenisPengiriman::class, 'jenis_pengiriman_id');
}
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eloquent sortBy - Specify asc or desc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649113/eloquent-sortby-specify-asc-or-desc)

Comment: @nice_dev Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::sortBy()

Comment: It will basically work on a collection. So, it should work as `BiayaPengiriman::latest()->get()->sortBy('jenis_pengiriman_id');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$biaya_pengiriman = BiayaPengiriman::all()->orderBy('your_field_name', 'DESC')-get();
```

at the end of your query in your index method. You don't need to do this in your model.